# Group data by some ids

Tags: mysql, sql, jasper-reports

English is not my native language, so I think an example may be better.

Here is what I want :

```
GROUP NAME 1 (when ids = 1,3 or 8) - SUM
id = 1
id = 3
id = 8

GROUP NAME 2 (when ids = 5 or 8) - SUM
id = 5 - NAME - SUM
id = 8 - NAME - SUM
```

...

As you see, I need to specify query (for *MySQL*) which ID are in the group.

Is this possible?

If not, is there another way? I think I can do this into many subreports, but it's not "clean".

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this:

```
     SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN (id =1 or id=3 or id=8) then WhichEverColumnYouWanaSum
            ELSE 0
            END )AS Group1,
            SUM (CASE WHEN (id =5 or id=8)  then WhichEverColumnYouWanaSum
            ELSE 0
            END)AS Group2
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, unfortunately, my query would have been very much more complex. So I made one subreport by id (I don't have a lot of id to do)